# Create http socket in javascript on client side in JSP and send text to network printer

Tags: javascript, jsp, sockets, http, zebra-printers

So first I want to describe my problem. I have a project (a website in JSP), where I must to print labels from browser. 
The problem is, this must happening in client side, because this network (where the printer will be) have a complicate security rules so I can't send this command from servlet (because physically it's not in the same network and portforward disabled),
and can't use applets in client side.

So my main idea that somehow I create a socket in JavaScript and send ZPL(Zebra Prog. Lang.) text to the printer (with http not websocket, because I think the printer cant handle this).

Here is an example for java: 
https://km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=content&id=SO7149&actp=LIST

Thanks for everything Best regards!

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: The browser security model will never allow you to create a server socket from the browser. You might be able to use an ActiveX control in internet explorer on windows; but I would not recommend that. Also, if you can't connect from the server to the printer you won't be able to connect from the server to the client (*because physically it's not in the same network and portforward disabled*).

Comment: Yes i know, this is the reason for my question, that have any idea for something that run in client side...
but okay so i must chose applet? or something desktop application that get this command from browser and do that i want...

Comment: @BlaskóPéter If the server A cannot connect to the printer on network B, then the server A also cannot connect to the user's computer on network B. You need to reconsider your design.

Comment: sure, but its a huge project, that not me build up... i just got this exercise that implement this module into... so i think i will create this applet because not another chance... but thanks for all the tips and the help ;)